# Macro to insert rows and fill is failing

Tags: excel, vba, insert, runtime-error

I've written the following macro to insert a specified number of rows into a table, and then to filldown, to re-populate the table with the correct forumulas.

I don't know why this is failing with an error at ActiveSheet.Rows(r).Insert with runtime error 1004. Insert method of Range class failed.

Could you help me out?

```
Sub SetKPIDuration()

Dim Duration As Integer, i As Integer, r As Integer

Duration = InputBox("Enter number of week for KPI to run (min 18)", 
"Duration of KPI", 18)

Select Case True
    Case Duration < 10
        Duration = 18
        GoTo IncreaseKPI
    Case Duration < Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A7:A150"))
        GoTo ReduceKPI
    Case Else
        GoTo IncreaseKPI
End Select

ReduceKPI:

Rows((Duration + 7) & ":150").Clear
Exit Sub

IncreaseKPI:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A7:A150"))
r = i + 7

While i < Duration

    ActiveSheet.Rows(r).insert

Wend

Range("A" & (r - 1) & ":" & "M" & (r + i)).filldown


Application.CutCopyMode = False


ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: so `i` is the maximum value in your range. Why insert values after the row identified by this maximum value, which could be larger than there can possibly be rows in the worksheet (some 104,876)?

Comment: Substitute "ActiveSheet" with a declared worksheet instead i.e. Worksheet.Rows(r).insert

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie. i is the maximum in the range to row 150. The idea is that the rows will be added to the bottom of the table. As in Column A, I have item numbers. I do not expect this sheet to top 1,000 entries.

Comment: Then `i = 150` would be sufficient. Again, `Max` gets the maximum _value_, not the maximum row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fully qualifying your ranges with full workbooks.worksheets.range paths.

Comment: That's worked. Now I just need to debug the reason that my fill-down is running over more rows than expected!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your line below might not be returning the result you want:

```
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A7:A150"))
```

if `i` is less than 18, you'll get an infinite loop here:

```
While i < Duration

    ActiveSheet.Rows(r).insert

Wend
```

...which eventually results in your 1004 error

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe that due to the Select Case element at the top of the VBA, if i were to be less than 18, this part of the VBA would not be run. Also, I am testing my VBA in break mode, and so each time I press F8 I iterate through 1 line. I get this error on the first pass on this line. Thank you for your thoughts so far! Although you did make me realise that I forgot to add i = i + 1 to that part. So you've really helped already!